# SQL Server 2017 HA Availability Group LSN issue

Tags: sql-server-2019, high-availability

I ran across a issue I have not seen before and not sure how to correct the issue. We have 2019 SQL setup using HA AV group and the other day I had to recover to a Point in Time but as I was taking the Full , DIFF and Log transactions from the Primary I ran across where I was not able to restore to a PIT. As I started to investigate I noticed that the LSN are not sequential and so the transaction logs are completely useless in restoring to PIT. There is significant gaps, I have the Primary replica backing up and full copy on the secondary do to requirements.  The error while performing transaction log backup is the transaction log is too recent. I think I am missing something but what?[image: image of break between lsn number]

Comment: did I understand correct you have a database in AlwaysOn AG version 2019 or 2017 and you want to restore it, however some log backups are missing so restore to your point in time failed? If so you should get list of log backup file names via built in report in SSMS or directly from msdb database  and find missing files. The query could be taken from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/ also you can examine existing files by RESTORE HEADERONLY to get lsns

Comment: Here is how you can run a report https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/04/sql-server-ssms-backup-and-restore-events-report/

Comment: 2019 HA AV 4 node - I was trying to gather all the full, diff and t-logs and unfortunately the full backup works, and one diff, the t-log do not work at all . The t-logs say missing LSN number or too recent for the LSN, so I am not able to do a PIT recovery.  I ran the script and it show in the edited image above the break between the LSN.

Comment: could you run the same query on other replicas?

Comment: I did and I am seeing the same thing on the replicas -   I went over the entire server to find any missing backups being done that I am not seeing, we verified that the servers are the only location for backups, I even changed how backups are being done for testing purposes but each time I have missing lsn's.